# Plotting PLSS (Township Range Section) Data to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, plss, township-range-section

I work for a Tribal Environmental Department and I have been asked to map locations and area of culturally significant sites. unfortunately for me, most of there data Township Range Section format.

Is there any way to plot this data in ArcMap 10.1 as a layer?

Comment: I used to map lease data against PLSS grids. We had a custom field with the format (something like `Meridian-Town-Range-Section`), then we would join the lease data by that field from another table.

Comment: The PLSS is a reference grid, rather than a coordinate system. You may want to read up on how it works (hover over the tag, click info for a good starting point). There's no way to plot a shape or specific point with that information unless it happens to be a reference grid cell. As Chad said, you can join data to a grid (which you can download as klewis mentioned - Arc doesn't come with it, but you may find it by adding a layer through ArcGIS Online), but everything with the same reference will then have the same shape. It really depends on how you want to map the data you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the latest Cadnsdi Land grid from each State. The Geocommunicator Site from the BLM has older data. This grid data is normally in the ESRI File Geodatabase format. You can query the FirstDivision layer (Sections) on PLSSID to reference your descriptions. For example, PLSSID = 'WY060400N0710W0'.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question so fast. I am fairly new at using ArcMap and performing GIS related tasks, so some of the items you suggested I really didn't understand. Do I have to download a file to my computer to map our states PLSS data or does the ArcMap program come with the capabilities to map PLSS?

Comment: A single State cadnsdi file geodatabase is normally about 1 gigabyte, unzipped. I recommend downloading to your PC. Your organization may have its own PLSS already. PLSS are just polygons, ArcMap can display polygons. You might want to query PLSS and save the selected areas to your own layer, for making maps, etc.